# Request for a page or service can take longer than usual to load or respond

Tags: jsp, tomcat6

It appears that after tomcat has been idle for some time, a first 
request for a page or service can take longer than usual to load or 
respond.

One possible cause that we're working on is that tomcat is unloading 
from memory some cached information, when it has been idle for some 
time, and the delay of this first request is caused by it picking back 
up again.  Is this a likely scenario?  If not, does anyone have any 
suggestions as to what might be happening?  If so, is there a way that I 
can tell tomcat not to clear whatever caches it might have cleared?

Thanks.

Comment: JSPs are compiled to servlet the first time they are requested, this would explain the behaviour if tomcat was restarted. But I think this has nothing to do when tomcat is running idle for some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just connection pool test connections issues.I put testOnBorrow parameter the issues is settled.

Answer (score 0):

A JSP is compiled to a servlet when it is requested the first time, so the JSP page will take longer to load the first time it is requested. However, this might be not your problem as you wrote you experience this behaviour when tomcat is running idle for some time.

However, in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html), i found out ther is a `jspIdleTimeout`:

> The amount of time in seconds a JSP can be idle before it is unloaded. A value of zero or less indicates never unload. Default -1

That might be a cause for your problem.

According to [this post](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/12/tomcat-705-beta-is-out.html), `jspIdleTimeout` is an init parameter:

> JSP Unloading is managed by a new configuration parameter, `jspIdleTimeout`.  If you have JSP's that have not been requested within that threshold, tomcat will unload the jsp.